# AOP solve academic example

Tags: ios, oop, design-patterns, aop, modularity

I have found an AOP example from Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Here is the interesting part:

```java
void transfer(Account fromAcc, Account toAcc, int amount, User user, Logger logger)
    throws Exception
{
    logger.info("Transferring money…");

    if (!isUserAuthorised(user, fromAcc)) {
        logger.info("User has no permission.");
        throw new UnauthorisedUserException();
    }

    if (fromAcc.getBalance() < amount) {
        logger.info("Insufficient funds.");
        throw new InsufficientFundsException();
    }

    fromAcc.withdraw(amount);
    toAcc.deposit(amount);
    database.commitChanges();  // Atomic operation.

    logger.info("Transaction successful.");
}
```

The Logger occurs 3 times in the method. How could I inject it for this 3 specific cases when as a rule all AOP containers has option like inject before method execution or after.
Here are the links for AOP containers that is possible to use under IOS
https://github.com/tokorom/BlockInjection

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot help with iOS development, but if you like I can post sample code in AspectJ deconstructing the Wikipedia sample Java code into aspects. I would only take the trouble to do so if you consider accepting that as a valid answer, though. I am waiting for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First, aspects can be injected *around* the method. Also you can advice (wrap) the methods that already advised by another aspect.
In your case it will look like 3 aspects: logging aspect(*around*), authorization aspect (*before*), positive balance aspect (*before*).